# Have I correctly use the word RATHER?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, tenses

***what is the difference between the following?***

***I'd rather you went home now.
  I'd rather you go home .***

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually simple present - expanded, it is:

> I *would* rather you went home now.

It actually form a mood, the subjunctive mood, which is rather fossilised and dated in English but nevertheless has its uses. ['would' on Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would?showCookiePolicy=true)

As for:

> - I'd rather you went home now
> - I'd rather you go home

I don't really parse them as having any difference;  I can't think of any situation where they two would have different meaning, unless it was in the following type of exchange:

- A: I want to stay.
- B: I'd rather you go home.

But even then, it would only be a rhetorical preference. I'll note that **traditionally**, the infinitive form (ie *go*) has been used with the subjunctive - for instance, *I'd rather we **be** quiet now*, rather than *I'd rather we **are** quiet now*, which is questionable at the very least.

In short: you've used it correctly. For present tense desires/preference, there's no difference I can discern between past/present in the subordinate clause, at least not with regard to everyday usage.